# Can COMAP leaking ball valve be fixed without removing it?

Tags: valve

The ball valve shown below (made by [COMAP](https://www.comap.pl/)) is leaking from its stem: guzzling when half-open, dripping when open or closed.  Can the leak be fixed without removing the valve? I don't see a stem packing nut.  I'd rather not drain the system it's connected to.

[image: Leaking ball valve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of those need to have the ball part removed through the body to get new seals in.

So just to fit new seals you will need to take that valve out of the system.

Given those old valves and the cost of new, I would just fit a new one.